# Edit @Entity after persistence within @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is it valid to first save a new `@Entity` and afterwards edit it within the same `@Transactional` method?

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository dao; //extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>

@Transactional
public Person createUpdatePerson(PersonDTO dto) {
   Person entity = dao.find(dto.getId());
   if (entity == null) {
      entity = new Person();
      dao.save(entity);     
   }

   //merge update
   entity.setName(dto.getName()); 
   entity.setAge(dto.getAge());
   //etc

   return entity;
}
```

Is this valid to do?

Comment: depends what "dao.save" does. As long as the object is still in "managed" state then yes

Comment: `entity-framework` is `.net`, you should remove this tag.

Comment: @NeilStockton it extends on CrudRepository, it can't just update object after saving by setters.

Comment: Since I've no idea what is a "CrudRepository" I've still no idea what state the object is in after that call. IF the object is "managed" then the calls to setters will be persisted at the end of a transactional method ... no need to make a further call to em.persist

Comment: @NeilStockton http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: I know of hibernate, and based upon that I can say that you need to persist/flush the session and then you can perform edit even in same Transactional method. Also, Is the above mentioned method from a DAO layer? If yes, then why do you need it at DAO layer, it should be in service-layer. Again, I might be wrong as I have not dealt with JPA.

Comment: @WeareBorg JPA is the same in that respect. Sadly nobody is focussing on object "state" here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save entity and update it after, but your updates wouldn't be saved. You should save your entity second time. The best solution is:

```
@Transactional
public Person createUpdatePerson(PersonDTO dto) {
   Person entity = dao.find(dto.getId());
   if (entity == null) {
      entity = new Person();
   }

   //merge update
   entity.setName(dto.getName()); 
   entity.setAge(dto.getAge());
   //etc
   return dao.save(entity);
}
```

This is save realisation of CrudRepository

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
}
```

It's already transactional and save entity into hibernate at same moment. And into database then it'll be flushed.

Comment: So it actually doesn't harm if I call `dao.save()` even though the `@Transactional` would care about merging the existing entity anywayS?

Comment: The main aims of @Transactional annotation are rolling back changes in exception case and prevent data changes if transaction in 'readOnly' mode. Use it for other aims is unsafely.